# running git or ssh client in docker as user: No user exists for uid

Tags: ssh, docker, authentication, passwd

#### Problem:

I'm trying to run a `git clone myuser@server:repo.git` from within a docker container. Inside the container (due to policy) I am the same user as on the docker host system (non-root) and have my home mounted.

Sadly when cloning from or trying to ssh into `server` i get an error message like this:

```
No user exists for uid 1337
```

#### MVCE:

To reproduce the problem you can run the following docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/$USER:/home/$USER -e HOME=/home/$USER -w /home/$USER -u $UID:100 --cap-drop=ALL kiesel/debian-ssh-client
```

and inside the container either of the following commands:

```
git clone myuser@server:repo.git
ssh -vT myuser@server
```

#### Workaround:

Adding a faked `/etc/passwd` with a line for my uid seems to fix the problem (e.g., `getent passwd $USER > /tmp/mypasswd`, then add a `-v /tmp/mypasswd:/etc/passwd:ro` to the `docker run` cmd).

Sadly this requires shadowing/modifying the container's `/etc/passwd`, which i can imagine will lead to trouble at some point.

#### Questions:

- Why is ssh (client) looking at the local (container's) `/etc/passwd`?
- Is there a simple way to deactivate that (with user permissions)?

Comment: Presumably to determine the user's home directory

Comment: This question was asked (& answered) in a very similar form on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57531352/1296709

Comment: The related code might be [this line](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L633). The code further references fields from a `struct` (I don't pretend to know, but) named "dir" and "name". So SSH likes to determine the username and home, like muru guessed.

Comment: You are injecting a user ID that doesn't exist in the docker container. `docker run --rm -it -v /home/$USER:/home/$USER -e HOME=/home/$USER -w /home/$USER  kiesel/debian-ssh-client` worked find for me. But the folder created from docker git is owned by root.

Answer (score 3):

Using this bash function:

```
function docker--run() {
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo 'docker--run [-v $PWD:/src] IMAGE'
        return 1
    fi
    # useradd for ubuntu (which has adduser as well)
    # adduser for alpine, others not tested
    docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh "$@" -c "
          [ -x /usr/sbin/useradd ] && useradd -m -u $(id -u) u1 -s /bin/sh || adduser -D -u $(id -u) u1 -s /bin/sh;
          exec su - u1"
}
```

You can run it as

```
docker--run -v /home/$USER:/home/u1 kiesel/debian-ssh-client
```

It will create a user `u1` with your userid in the docker container and then switch to that user.